# Testing performance / connection speed of (Oracle) database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, oracle11g

I have two test environments. My application is performing much worst on the seconds one. I suspect that this because the first one system is using database which runs on better hardware (more CPU, faster connection). I would like to verify my claims somehow. Are there any tools, which would help me with that? Should it helpful, I am using Oracle 11g and my app is using Hibernate to connect to the database.

Mind you, I am not interested in profiling my schema. I would like to compare how fast is the same database (meaning schema + data) on two different machines.

If you are interested, why I suspect that database is the problem: I profiled my application during tests on those two environments. During the second test environment methods responsible for connecting to database (namely org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery()) are using much more of the CPU time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer the question:** I believe you'd use JMeter to profile the two environments, and get comprehensive data out of the tests you run. VisualVM will also be helpful, but that depends on the kind of data you need, and how you need to present (or analyze) it.

But as for the general problem, is the data on the two databases *exactly* the same? Because if this is not the case, some possibilities are open - your transactions might be depending on data that is locked by another process (therefore, you'd need to look at your transactions and the transaction isolation they use).

Comment: couldn't have given a more comprehensive answer myself